# How do I stop a JS driven full page scroll from jumping to the start/end

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Im very new to using/writing JS and i've just grabbed this plugin for a full page vertical scroll. I works just how I want however I want to stop the function of it scrolling to the first slide from the last (if you scroll down from the last slide) and vice versa from the first to the last (if you scroll up).

Could someone please point me in the right direction in the JS code to what i have to remove/edit to have it just stop scrolling down at the last frame and stop scrolling up at the first frame.

Thanks

```js
!function($){

  var defaults = {
    sectionContainer: "section",
    easing: "ease",
    animationTime: 1000,
    pagination: true,
    updateURL: false,
    keyboard: true,
    beforeMove: null,
    afterMove: null,
    loop: true,
    responsiveFallback: false,
    direction : 'vertical'
 };

 $.fn.swipeEvents = function() {
      return this.each(function() {

        var startX,
            startY,
            $this = $(this);

        $this.bind('touchstart', touchstart);

        function touchstart(event) {
          var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
          if (touches && touches.length) {
            startX = touches[0].pageX;
            startY = touches[0].pageY;
            $this.bind('touchmove', touchmove);
          }
        }

        function touchmove(event) {
          var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
          if (touches && touches.length) {
            var deltaX = startX - touches[0].pageX;
            var deltaY = startY - touches[0].pageY;

            if (deltaX >= 50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeLeft");
            }
            if (deltaX <= -50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeRight");
            }
            if (deltaY >= 50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeUp");
            }
            if (deltaY <= -50) {
              $this.trigger("swipeDown");
            }
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) >= 50 || Math.abs(deltaY) >= 50) {
              $this.unbind('touchmove', touchmove);
            }
          }
        }

      });
    };


  $.fn.onepage_scroll = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
        el = $(this),
        sections = $(settings.sectionContainer)
        total = sections.length,
        status = "off",
        topPos = 0,
        leftPos = 0,
        lastAnimation = 0,
        quietPeriod = 500,
        paginationList = "";

    $.fn.transformPage = function(settings, pos, index) {
      if (typeof settings.beforeMove == 'function') settings.beforeMove(index);

      // Just a simple edit that makes use of modernizr to detect an IE8 browser and changes the transform method into
     // an top animate so IE8 users can also use this script.
     if($('html').hasClass('ie8')){
        if (settings.direction == 'horizontal') {
          var toppos = (el.width()/100)*pos;
          $(this).animate({left: toppos+'px'},settings.animationTime);
        } else {
          var toppos = (el.height()/100)*pos;
          $(this).animate({top: toppos+'px'},settings.animationTime);
        }
     } else{
       $(this).css({
         "-webkit-transform": ( settings.direction == 'horizontal' ) ? "translate3d(" + pos + "%, 0, 0)" : "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
         "-webkit-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
         "-moz-transform": ( settings.direction == 'horizontal' ) ? "translate3d(" + pos + "%, 0, 0)" : "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
         "-moz-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
         "-ms-transform": ( settings.direction == 'horizontal' ) ? "translate3d(" + pos + "%, 0, 0)" : "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
         "-ms-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
         "transform": ( settings.direction == 'horizontal' ) ? "translate3d(" + pos + "%, 0, 0)" : "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
         "transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing
       });
     }
      $(this).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
        if (typeof settings.afterMove == 'function') settings.afterMove(index);
      });
    }

    $.fn.moveDown = function() {
      var el = $(this)
      index = $(settings.sectionContainer +".active").data("index");
      current = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + index + "']");
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (index + 1) + "']");
      if(next.length < 1) {
        if (settings.loop == true) {
          pos = 0;
          next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='1']");
        } else {
          return
        }

      }else {
        pos = (index * 100) * -1;
      }
      if (typeof settings.beforeMove == 'function') settings.beforeMove( next.data("index"));
      current.removeClass("active")
      next.addClass("active");
      if(settings.pagination == true) {
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + index + "']").removeClass("active");
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + next.data("index") + "']").addClass("active");
      }

      $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
      $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

      if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
        var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (index + 1);
        history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
      }
      el.transformPage(settings, pos, next.data("index"));
    }

    $.fn.moveUp = function() {
      var el = $(this)
      index = $(settings.sectionContainer +".active").data("index");
      current = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + index + "']");
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (index - 1) + "']");

      if(next.length < 1) {
        if (settings.loop == true) {
          pos = ((total - 1) * 100) * -1;
          next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='"+total+"']");
        }
        else {
          return
        }
      }else {
        pos = ((next.data("index") - 1) * 100) * -1;
      }
      if (typeof settings.beforeMove == 'function') settings.beforeMove(next.data("index"));
      current.removeClass("active")
      next.addClass("active")
      if(settings.pagination == true) {
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + index + "']").removeClass("active");
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + next.data("index") + "']").addClass("active");
      }
      $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
      $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

      if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
        var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (index - 1);
        history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
      }
      el.transformPage(settings, pos, next.data("index"));
    }

    $.fn.moveTo = function(page_index) {
      current = $(settings.sectionContainer + ".active")
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']");
      if(next.length > 0) {
        if (typeof settings.beforeMove == 'function') settings.beforeMove(next.data("index"));
        current.removeClass("active")
        next.addClass("active")
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + ".active").removeClass("active");
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']").addClass("active");
        $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
        $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

        pos = ((page_index - 1) * 100) * -1;

        if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
            var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (page_index - 1);
            history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
        }
        el.transformPage(settings, pos, page_index);
      }
    }

    function responsive() {
      //start modification
      var valForTest = false;
      var typeOfRF = typeof settings.responsiveFallback

      if(typeOfRF == "number"){
       valForTest = $(window).width() < settings.responsiveFallback;
      }
      if(typeOfRF == "boolean"){
       valForTest = settings.responsiveFallback;
      }
      if(typeOfRF == "function"){
       valFunction = settings.responsiveFallback();
       valForTest = valFunction;
       typeOFv = typeof valForTest;
       if(typeOFv == "number"){
        valForTest = $(window).width() < valFunction;
       }
      }

      //end modification
      if (valForTest) {
        $("body").addClass("disabled-onepage-scroll");
        $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll');
        el.swipeEvents().unbind("swipeDown swipeUp");
      } else {
        if($("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) {
          $("body").removeClass("disabled-onepage-scroll");
          $("html, body, .wrapper").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        }


        el.swipeEvents().bind("swipeDown",  function(event){
          if (!$("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) event.preventDefault();
          el.moveUp();
        }).bind("swipeUp", function(event){
          if (!$("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) event.preventDefault();
          el.moveDown();
        });

        $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
          init_scroll(event, delta);
        });
      }
    }


    function init_scroll(event, delta) {
        deltaOfInterest = delta;
        var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
        if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + settings.animationTime) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        if (deltaOfInterest < 0) {
          el.moveDown()
        } else {
          el.moveUp()
        }
        lastAnimation = timeNow;
    }

    // Prepare everything before binding wheel scroll

    el.addClass("onepage-wrapper").css("position","relative");
    $.each( sections, function(i) {
      $(this).css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: topPos + "%"
      }).addClass("section").attr("data-index", i+1);


      $(this).css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: ( settings.direction == 'horizontal' )
          ? leftPos + "%"
          : 0,
        top: ( settings.direction == 'vertical' || settings.direction != 'horizontal' )
          ? topPos + "%"
          : 0
      });

      if (settings.direction == 'horizontal')
        leftPos = leftPos + 100;
      else
        topPos = topPos + 100;


      if(settings.pagination == true) {
        paginationList += "<li><a data-index='"+(i+1)+"' href='#" + (i+1) + "'></a></li>"
      }
    });

    el.swipeEvents().bind("swipeDown",  function(event){
      if (!$("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) event.preventDefault();
      el.moveUp();
    }).bind("swipeUp", function(event){
      if (!$("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) event.preventDefault();
      el.moveDown();
    });

    // Create Pagination and Display Them
    if (settings.pagination == true) {
      if ($('ul.onepage-pagination').length < 1) $("<ul class='onepage-pagination'></ul>").prependTo("body");

      if( settings.direction == 'horizontal' ) {
        posLeft = (el.find(".onepage-pagination").width() / 2) * -1;
        el.find(".onepage-pagination").css("margin-left", posLeft);
      } else {
        posTop = (el.find(".onepage-pagination").height() / 2) * -1;
        el.find(".onepage-pagination").css("margin-top", posTop);
      }
      $('ul.onepage-pagination').html(paginationList);
    }

    if(window.location.hash != "" && window.location.hash != "#1") {
      init_index =  window.location.hash.replace("#", "")

      if (parseInt(init_index) <= total && parseInt(init_index) > 0) {
        $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + init_index + "']").addClass("active")
        $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+ init_index)
        if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + init_index + "']").addClass("active");

        next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (init_index) + "']");
        if(next) {
          next.addClass("active")
          if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + (init_index) + "']").addClass("active");
          $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
          $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))
          if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
            var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (init_index);
            history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
          }
        }
        pos = ((init_index - 1) * 100) * -1;
        el.transformPage(settings, pos, init_index);
      } else {
        $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='1']").addClass("active")
        $("body").addClass("viewing-page-1")
        if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='1']").addClass("active");
      }
    }else{
      $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='1']").addClass("active")
      $("body").addClass("viewing-page-1")
      if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='1']").addClass("active");
    }

    if(settings.pagination == true)  {
      $(".onepage-pagination li a").click(function (){
        var page_index = $(this).data("index");
        el.moveTo(page_index);
      });
    }


    $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
      if(!$("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) init_scroll(event, delta);
    });


    if(settings.responsiveFallback != false) {
      $(window).resize(function() {
        responsive();
      });

      responsive();
    }

    if(settings.keyboard == true) {
      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();

        if (!$("body").hasClass("disabled-onepage-scroll")) {
          switch(e.which) {
            case 38:
              if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveUp()
            break;
            case 40:
              if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveDown()
            break;
            case 32: //spacebar
              if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveDown()
            break;
            case 33: //pageg up
              if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveUp()
            break;
            case 34: //page dwn
              if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveDown()
            break;
            case 36: //home
              el.moveTo(1);
            break;
            case 35: //end
              el.moveTo(total);
            break;
            default: return;
          }
        }

      });
    }
    return false;
  }


}(window.jQuery);
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
}

body, .onepage-wrapper, html {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.onepage-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.onepage-wrapper .section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.onepage-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.onepage-pagination li {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.onepage-pagination li a{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;
  
}
.onepage-pagination li a:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.onepage-pagination li a.active:before{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -4px;
  left: 8px;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll, .disabled-onepage-scroll .wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper .section {
  position: relative !important;
  top: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}


.disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-pagination {
  display: none;
}

body.disabled-onepage-scroll, .disabled-onepage-scroll .onepage-wrapper, html {
  position: inherit;
}

.page1 {
 background-color:#DEDEDE;
}

.page2 {
 background-color:#D17879;
}

.page3 {
 background-color:#DFEB29;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>

<link href="onepage-scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="main">
<section class="page1">
... SECTION 1 ...
</section>
<section class="page2">
... SECTION 2 ...
</section>
<section class="page3">
... SECTION 3 ...
</section>
<section class="page1">
... SECTION 1 ...
</section>
<section class="page2">
... SECTION 2 ...
</section>
<section class="page3">
... SECTION 3 ...
</section>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".main").onepage_scroll({
sectionContainer: "section"
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the loop option to false.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        loop: true,
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In code, you are setting it as true while in the answer you are suggesting for false. What do you want to say actually?